# Sql server consuming more memory than max memory limit

Tags: sql-server, memory-management, memory-leaks

Sqlserver.exe showing memory greater than max memory limit lock pages also enabled its confusing

Answer (score 0):

AS stated [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8375/33311)

SQL Servers max memory setting defines the limits for buffer pool usage only. There will be variable but significant allocations required over and above that limit.

[Jonathan Kehayias's](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2009/07/07/understanding-the-vas-reservation-aka-memtoleave-in-sql-server.aspx), [Christian Bolton](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/christian/archive/2008/01/07/sql-server-memtoleave-vas-and-64-bit.aspx) and [John Samson](http://www.johnsansom.com/sql-server-memory-configuration-determining-memtoleave-settings/#axzz1edYFoxbs) have level 300/400 posts on the topic. [Brent Ozar](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/) has an easier to read article that might be a better place to start.

Also related: [SQL Server 2008 R2 “Ghost Memory”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7060/sql-server-2008-r2-ghost-memory)

Answer (score 0):

**Min & Max Server Memory**

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  → Right Click the Server → Properties →Memory → Server Memory Options → Minimum server memory (In MB): = 0 and Maximum server memory (In MB): = 2147483647

Configure this memory allocation Based on the RAM installed in the DB Server.

For Ex:

IF DB server is installed with **6 GB of RAM**, then maintain the **20%** breadth space for the OS installed in the server.
For 6 GB of RAM, Maximum server memory (In MB) will be = **4915** for the SQL server.

Right Click the Server → Properties →Security → Login Auditing → Enable the Failed logins only. This option will avoid the log write and memory log space will be saved.